# What happens if a dragon lacrima of another element is implanted?

Tags: fairy-tail

In fairy tail, we know that the third generation dragon slayers have been taught dragon slayer magic by dragons and also that they have dragon lacrimas implanted.
If a dragon lacrima of an element of different type is implanted what will happen?  Will they gain two types of dragon slayer magic?
( For example if Sting is implanted with a fire element type dragon lacrima will he gain two types of dragon slayer magic? i.e. holy light type magic taught by Vicelogia and fire type magic gained from the lacrima)

Comment: Probably. You can be taught two different kinds of magic, so why wouldn't two dragons be able to teach you two different kinds of dragon slayer magic? The same would probably go for the lacrimas, but I don't think there is any proof of a dragon slayer having two elements other than Natsu who is somehow magically able to keep using Laxus' magic, but it was never explained why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spoilers to recent Manga chapters, But to be put simply they gain the ability to use and presumably eat that element. This is shown by

> One of the Elite Members of the Alvarez Empire,[God Serena](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/God_Serena), who used to be a wizard saint, rank 1, who had 8 Dragon Lacrima implanted into his body.

This is shown when (Even Bigger Spoiler):

> he uses the Cavern, Purgatory, and Sea King Dragon slayer magics in rapid succession to beat down four wizard saints ranked 2,3,4,and 5. Draculos Hyberion, Wolfheim, Warrod Sequen, and Jura Neekis were all incapacitated by his 3 attacks of those 3 dragon slayer magics. He then prepared to finish them off with Gale Dragon Slayer Magic, but was interrupted before he used that one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is dependent on the Dragon Slayer. Natsu has done this multiple times (Laxus, Zancrow) and Gajeel has accomplished it once. It could be a similar process like when people take small amounts of poison to build a tolerance to it. As was seen, Natsu became sick after using lighting, but over time it seems he has been accustomed to it as it doesn't have such an adverse effect on him when he uses it.

Answer (score 0):

The lacramas shouldnt hold restrictions since there is a character with 8 dragon slayer elements from them. But for dragon slayers to gain dual elemental modes like Natsus Lightning Flame Dragon mode or Gajeels Iron Shadow Dragon mode, i personally believe it can only be taken from 2nd or 3rd generation dragon slayers. Laxus gave Natsu his lightning in a similar way to how Natsu had consumed the ethernano and other flames, but only the lightning has stayed with him without being a fire based attack. I like to believe that since Laxus has a lightning Lacrama, his lightning was shared by having enough energy consumed to create a new lacrama in Natsu. Gajeel then did the same with Rouges shadow by absorbing the power from the lacrama half of Rouge instead of the shadow magic taught by his dragon. The final example i could think of was future Rouge saying he "took" Stings magic after killing him. The only possible way for that is through his lacrama, turning Rouges future self into a White Shadow Dragon